# Android / Java: Check if url is valid youtube url

Tags: java, android, regex, youtube

I want to check if an url is valid youtube url so that I can shown in view otherwise I will hide the view.

Is there any regular expression in Java that can help me to check if url is valid. Currently I am using this regex but I guess it's not the one I want:

```
String youTubeURl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Btr8uOU0BkI";
String pattern = "https?:\\/\\/(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\\.)?(?:youtu\\.be\\/|youtube\\.com\\S*[^\\w\\-\\s])([\\w\\-]{11})(?=[^\\w\\-]|$)(?![?=&+%\\w]*(?:['\"][^<>]*>|<\\/a>))[?=&+%\\w]*";
 if (!youTubeURl.isEmpty() && youTubeURl.matches(pattern)) {
              /// Valid youtube URL
  }
 else{
   // Not Valid youtube URL
}
```

Comment: try to make http-connection with url and check response code

Answer (score 13):

This works for me.

```
public static boolean isYoutubeUrl(String youTubeURl)
{
       boolean success;
       String pattern = "^(http(s)?:\\/\\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\\.com)?\\/.+";
       if (!youTubeURl.isEmpty() && youTubeURl.matches(pattern))
       {
           success = true;
       }
       else
       {
           // Not Valid youtube URL
           success = false;
       }
       return success;
  }
```

If you want to retrieve the Youtube videoId you can use the following function.

```
public static String getVideoIdFromYoutubeUrl(String youtubeUrl)
{
       /*
           Possibile Youtube urls.
           http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WK0YhfKqdaI
           http://www.youtube.com/embed/WK0YhfKqdaI
           http://www.youtube.com/v/WK0YhfKqdaI
           http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/WK0YhfKqdaI?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0
           http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WK0YhfKqdaI
           http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WK0YhfKqdaI
           http://www.youtube.com/e/WK0YhfKqdaI
           http://youtu.be/WK0YhfKqdaI
        */
       String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/|youtu.be\\/|\\/v\\/|\\/e\\/|watch\\?v%3D|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C\u200B2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*";
       Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
       //url is youtube url for which you want to extract the id.
       Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(youtubeUrl);
       if (matcher.find()) {
           return matcher.group();
       }
       return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(youTubeURl).matches()
```

It will return True if URL is valid and false if URL is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Use [android.webkit.URLUtil.isValidUrl(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#isValidUrl%28java.lang.String%29) to check if url is valid. And then you can check if url contains Youtube string.

Like

```
private boolean isValidUrl(String url) {

    if (url == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
        // Check host of url if youtube exists
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        if ("www.youtube.com".equals(uri.getHost())) {
            return true;
        }
        // Other way You can check into url also like 
        //if (url.startsWith("https://www.youtube.com/")) {
            //return true;
        //}
    }
    // In other any case
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what about " https://youtu.be/zuf8A0udHrs " in this case? and i having trouble in fetching YouTube Video Id from url.

Comment: This is not a valid youtube url.

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve what you want you should use this Regex like so:

```
private static final Pattern youtubePattern = Pattern.compile("^(http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/.+");
private boolean isValid = youtubePattern.matcher(youtubeUrl).matches();
```

where `youtubeUrl` can be any URL of the following list:

- http://youtu.be/t-ZRX8984sc
- http://youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-ZRX8984sc
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwGFalTRHDA&feature=related
- http://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r5nB9u4jjy4
- https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDZkgJZDyUnqwB070OyP72g
- youtube.com/n17B_uFF4cA
- youtube.com/iwGFalTRHDA
- http://youtu.be/n17B_uFF4cA
- https://youtube.com/iwGFalTRHDA
- https://youtube.com/channel/UCDZkgJZDyUnqwB070OyP72g

This regex can match any types of URLs related to youtube.com

Comment: Some of the URLs are dead!

Comment: Yes, but the aim is the same, it validate whether or not the URL is from Youtube

Comment: @RobertoOsorioMcNulty regex in the string should be "^(http(s)?:\\/\\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\\.com)?\\/.+"

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't check if URL is valid or not. It only checks for strings "youtube" & "youtu.be" in your URL. Following is the regex

```
String yourUrl = "https://youtu.be/Xh0-x1RFEOY";
yourUrl.matches(".*(youtube|youtu.be).*")
```

" .*  " at beginning & end means that there could be anything on left & right of the expression(youtube & youtu.be) you are checking.

**NOTE:** This has nothing to do with the validity of the URL

Comment: This will not work if you have "youtube" or "youtu.be" words in url. For example, link to this post also returns true