# How mute volume of YouTube video in android using YouTube API

Tags: android

I have create an android application which is working fine but problem is that I want play YouTube video on mute because of we'll be playing song in background. So is it possible to play a muted YouTube video in my app?
and hide all YouTube player controls and video is auto play.

Comment: you can put your Device in Silent with Vibrate mode. hence Volume is ZERO. even you play a song or else..

Comment: which media player you have used to play songs?

Comment: Found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this fantastic [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#full-screen) library. Basically this libs doesn't allow you to set the volume so you have to create your own layout (and manage yourself the volume) that inflate the UI of the youtube player.
This is a custom UI that i've created.

[image: custom UI example]

Once you have followed the [Quick start guide](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#quick-start) you can create your custom UI.

layout_custom_youtube_player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewYoutubeCustomUI"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewYoutubeTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonMuteUnMute"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_volume_off_white_24dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbarYoutube"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonPlayPause"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.ui.views.YouTubePlayerSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/youTubePlayerSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            app:fontSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
            app:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonEnterExitFullscreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_enter_fullscreen_white_24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomYoutubePlayerUIController.java

```
package com.mcsoft.custom_youtube_handler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mcsoft.R;
import com.mcsoft.helper.SharedPreferencesHandler;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.PlayerConstants;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.YouTubePlayerFullScreenListener;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.utils.YouTubePlayerTracker;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.ui.views.YouTubePlayerSeekBar;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.ui.views.YouTubePlayerSeekBarListener;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class CustomYoutubePlayerUIController extends AbstractYouTubePlayerListener implements YouTubePlayerFullScreenListener
{
    private final View playerUi;
    public static final int DELAY_TIME_SHOW_PLAY_PAUSE_BUTTON = 3000;
    private Context context;
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;

    // viewYoutubeCustomUI is used to intercept clicks on the WebView, I don't want the user to be able to click the WebView directly.
    private View viewYoutubeCustomUI;
    private View progressbarYoutube;
    private YouTubePlayerSeekBar youTubePlayerSeekBar;
    private final YouTubePlayerTracker playerTracker;
    private boolean fullscreen = false;
    private boolean isMuted = true;
    private SharedPreferencesHandler sharedPreferencesHandler;

    public CustomYoutubePlayerUIController (Context context, View customPlayerUi, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView) {
        this.playerUi = customPlayerUi;
        this.context = context;
        this.youTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
        this.youTubePlayerView = youTubePlayerView;
        sharedPreferencesHandler = new SharedPreferencesHandler(context);
        playerTracker = new YouTubePlayerTracker();
        this.youTubePlayer.addListener(playerTracker);
        initViews(customPlayerUi);
    }

    private void initViews(View playerUi)
    {
        youTubePlayerSeekBar = playerUi.findViewById(R.id.youTubePlayerSeekBar);
        youTubePlayer.addListener(youTubePlayerSeekBar);
        viewYoutubeCustomUI = playerUi.findViewById(R.id.viewYoutubeCustomUI);
        progressbarYoutube = playerUi.findViewById(R.id.progressbarYoutube);

        final ImageButton imageButtonPlayPause = playerUi.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonPlayPause);
        ImageButton imageButtonEnterExitFullscreen = playerUi.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonEnterExitFullscreen);
        final ImageButton imageButtonMuteUnMute = playerUi.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonMuteUnMute);
        TextView textViewYoutubeTitle = playerUi.findViewById(R.id.textViewYoutubeTitle);
        textViewYoutubeTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewYoutubeCustomUI.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    imageButtonPlayPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // hide your button here
                            imageButtonPlayPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, DELAY_TIME_SHOW_PLAY_PAUSE_BUTTON);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        // Manage volume
        imageButtonMuteUnMute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (!isMuted)
                {
                    youTubePlayer.setVolume(0);
                    imageButtonMuteUnMute.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_volume_off_white_24dp));
                }
                else
                {
                    youTubePlayer.setVolume(100);
                    imageButtonMuteUnMute.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_volume_up_white_24dp));
                }
                isMuted = !isMuted;
            }
        });

        youTubePlayerSeekBar.setYoutubePlayerSeekBarListener(new YouTubePlayerSeekBarListener() {
            @Override
            public void seekTo(float time) {
                youTubePlayer.seekTo(time);
            }
        });

        imageButtonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if (isMuted)
                {
                    youTubePlayer.setVolume(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    youTubePlayer.setVolume(100);
                }  
                if (playerTracker.getState() == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.PLAYING)
                {
                    youTubePlayer.pause();
                    imageButtonPlayPause.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_white_24dp));
                }
                else
                {
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    imageButtonPlayPause.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_white_24dp));
                }
            }
        });

        imageButtonEnterExitFullscreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if (fullscreen)
                {
                    youTubePlayerView.exitFullScreen();
                }
                else
                {
                    youTubePlayerView.enterFullScreen();
                }
                fullscreen = !fullscreen;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
        progressbarYoutube.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChange(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, @NonNull PlayerConstants.PlayerState state) {
        if(state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.PLAYING || state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.PAUSED || state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.VIDEO_CUED)
            viewYoutubeCustomUI.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent));
        else
        if(state == PlayerConstants.PlayerState.BUFFERING)
            viewYoutubeCustomUI.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent));
    }

    @Override
    public void onYouTubePlayerEnterFullScreen() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams viewParams = playerUi.getLayoutParams();
        viewParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        viewParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        playerUi.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void onYouTubePlayerExitFullScreen() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams viewParams = playerUi.getLayoutParams();
        viewParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        viewParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        playerUi.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
    }
}
```

Now in your activity you have to inflate the Youtube Layout

```
View customPlayerUi = youTubePlayerView.inflateCustomPlayerUi(R.layout.layout_custom_youtube_player);

youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
       @Override
       public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer)
       {
          CustomYoutubePlayerUIController customPlayerUiController = new CustomYoutubePlayerUIController(context, holder.customPlayerUi, youTubePlayer, youTubePlayerView);
          youTubePlayer.addListener(customPlayerUiController);
          youTubePlayerView.addFullScreenListener(customPlayerUiController);
          if(sharedPreferencesHandler.getAutoplayYoutubeVideo())
          {
             youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
          }
          else
          {
             youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, 0);
          }
       }
    });
```

**NOTE**

If you want to extract a youtube's video id from a link you can check at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030892/android-java-check-if-url-is-valid-youtube-url/55470188#55470188).

**IMPORTANT**

Using [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#full-screen) you needs to migrate your `dependencies` (follow [this guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)) because you need to add `YouTubePlayerView` as a `LifecycleObserver`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look to this:

https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/YouTubePlayerActivity

As you can see you have one feature:
Media Volume Support

**While watching YouTube Player, users should be able to set media volume**

Comment: sorry but i want set volume programmatic when video is start. hide all YouTube player controls,