# Set the volume of youtubeplayer api over time android

Tags: android, youtube-api, volume

I have been integrating the YoutubePlayer API for with my Android project. The videos from the playlist are working well. What I am trying to do is have the audio start low and fade in over 30seconds.

What I have done so far, for some reason is doing somthing really weird. It set it to max volume and if you try to turn it down it turns it back up again really straight away.

The way I thought I could do it was to set the audio manager to a 0 volume and then on an ontick timer raise that by 1 until it got to the max volume.

The code below was my attempt, but like I said it is doing weird things.

Thanks for your help

```
                  youTubePlayer.loadPlaylist(playListTitle);

                  final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                  // Add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance
                  youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {


                      @Override
                      public void onLoaded(String arg0) {

                          youTubePlayer.play();

                          audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);

                          Integer volumeRaisingTime = 30000;

                          new CountDownTimer(volumeRaisingTime, 1000) {

                              Integer deviceMaxVolume = 20;
                              Integer devicevolume = 0;
                              public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                  audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
                                  if (devicevolume > deviceMaxVolume){

                                      devicevolume++;

                                     Log.d("Device Volume:", ""+devicevolume);
                                  }


                              }

                              public void onFinish() {

                              }

                          }.start();

                      }
```

Comment: Hi you can find something that can help you at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176157/how-mute-volume-of-youtube-video-in-android-using-youtube-api/55703169#55703169).